# Problem with cell content centering in longtable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable, center

I have a problem with my table encoded as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\C}{~$^\circ C$}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{longtable}[c]{>{\centering}m{0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} |>{\centering}m{0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\endhead
\endfoot
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\tiny * -- some note}\\
\endlastfoot
  \caption{Some title}\\
\ce{MH2} & \ce{Mg2NiH4} \cite{} & \ce{NaNH2} \\* \hline
\ce{Mg}: \newline
1:2 -- 420\C \cite{} \newline
1:2 -- 490\C \cite{} \newline
1:2 z 5\% \cite{}: \newline
\ce{TiF3} -- 470\C \newline
\ce{TiO2} -- 470\C \newline
\ce{Zr} -- 470\C \newline
\ce{Si} -- 470\C \newline
\ce{BCC} -- 470\C \newline
M = Ca \cite{}: \newline 
1:6 -- 390\C & 
        5:4 -- 350\C & 
                1:1 -- 330 \C* \cite{} \newline
                2:1 z Co-Ni-B \cite{}: \newline
                1$\%_{wag}$ -- $\sim$300\C \newline
                3$\%_{wag}$ -- $\sim$285\C \newline
                5$\%_{wag}$ -- $\sim$285\C \newline
                7$\%_{wag}$ -- $\sim$258\C \\ \hline
M(AlH4)x & \ce{Li3AlH6} \cite{} & \ce{MBH4} \\* \hline
\ce{Li} \cite{}: \newline
1:1 -- 446\C \newline
1:1 z 5\% \ce{TiF3} -- $\sim$300\C \newline
\ce{2NaAlH4}+\ce{Ca(BH4)2} \newline 
z 5$\%_{wag}$ \ce{TiF3} -- 400\C \cite{} &
        3:1 -- 400\C \newline
        2:1 -- 400\C \newline
        1:1 (1h) -- 400\C \newline
        1:1 (24h) -- 392\C \newline
        1:2 -- $\sim$430\C \newline
        1:3 -- $\sim$430\C &
                \ce{Li}; 38:62: \newline
                350\C \cite{} \newline
                $\sim$420\C \cite{} \newline
                60$\%_{obj}$  -- $\sim$333\C \cite{} \newline
                \ce{K} 32:68 -- $\sim$472\C \cite{} \newline
                \ce{Mg} -- $\sim$205\C \cite{} \newline
                \ce{Li, K, Mg i Ca} \newline
                1:1:1:1 -- $\sim$330\C \cite{}\\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can clearly see, the rows inside some cells are not centered (vertical lines added to make it easier to see). I tried to find a solution but got stuck ... Sorry if the code is too detailed, but I wanted to be as specific as possible. The thing I want to accomplish is of course to center all the rows in each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Welcome to TeX.SE!
- The first column should be slightly wider then the rest two, that contents can be proper centered
- If you convert table code to `tabularray` table and use `siunitx` package for units in table, the MWE of your table become:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, onecolumn, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{color, colortbl}  % not needed in this MWE
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Some title},
  label = {tab:long?},
note{*} = {some note}
                ]{colspec = {X[1.1, c] X[0.9, c] X[c]},
                  rowhead = 1,
                  hlines, vlines
                  }
\ce{MH2}    & \ce{Mg2NiH4} \cite{}  & \ce{NaNH2} \\* 

{\ce{Mg}: \\
    1:2   -- \SI{420}{\celsius} \cite{} \\
    1:2   -- \SI{490}{\celsius} \cite{} \\
    1:2 z 5\% \cite{}: \\
    \ce{TiF3} -- \SI{470}{\celsius}     \\
    \ce{TiO2} -- \SI{470}{\celsius}     \\
    \ce{Zr}   -- \SI{470}{\celsius}     \\
    \ce{Si}   -- \SI{470}{\celsius}     \\
    \ce{BCC}  -- \SI{470}{\celsius}     \\
    M = Ca \cite{}:                     \\
1:6 -- \SI{390}{\celsius}
}
    &   5:4 --  \SI{350}{\celsius}  
        &   {1:1 -- \SI{330}{\celsius}\TblrNote{*} \cite{}   \\
            2:1 z Co-Ni-B \cite{}:                          \\
            $\SI{1}{\%}_{wag}$ -- \SI{\sim 300}{\celsius}           \\
            $\SI{3}{\%}_{wag}$ -- \SI{\sim 285}{\celsius}           \\
            $\SI{5}{\%}_{wag}$ -- \SI{\sim 285}{\celsius}            \\
            $\SI{7}{\%}_{wag}$ -- \SI{\sim 258}{\celsius}
            }            \\ 

M(AlH4)x 
    & \ce{Li3AlH6} \cite{} 
        & \ce{MBH4}             \\* 

{\ce{Li} \cite{}:               \\
    1:1 -- \SI{446}{\celsius}   \\
    1:1 z \SI{5}{\%} TiF\textsubscript{3} -- \SI{\sim 300}{\celsius}   \\
    \ce{2NaAlH4} + \ce{Ca(BH4)2}        \\
    z $\SI{5}{\%}_{wag}$ -- \SI{\sim 400}{\celsius} \cite{}
}   &   {3:1 -- \SI{400}{\celsius}      \\
        2:1  -- \SI{400}{\celsius}      \\
        1:1 (1h)  -- \SI{400}{\celsius} \\
        1:1 (24h) -- \SI{392}{\celsius} \\
        1:2 -- \SI{\sim 430}{\celsius}  \\
        1:3 -- \SI{\sim 430}{\celsius}  
        }   &   {\ce{Li}; 38:62:                \\
                \SI{350}{\celsius} \cite{}      \\
                \SI{\sim 420}{\celsius} \cite{} \\
                $\SI{60}{\%}_{obj}$  -- \SI{\sim 333}{\celsius} \cite{} \\
                \ce{K} 32:68 -- \SI{\sim 472}{\celsius} \cite{}         \\
                \ce{Mg} -- \SI{\sim 205}{\celsius} \cite{}              \\
                \ce{Li, K, Mg i Ca}             \\
                1:1:1:1 -- \SI{\sim 330}{\celsius} \cite{}
                }   \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer, that contents of cells are vertical centered too, than you only need change column specification to

```
colspec = {X[1.1, c, m] X[0.9, c, m] X[c, m]},
```

and table will have the following form:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask if a longtblr behaves like a longtable in case the table is longer than a page? What should I change to get the same cell borders as in my code?

Comment: @Piotrek, a `longtblr`  behave as `longtable`. To see this, just add more rows in table that it be longer than one page.